# How does Knowledge Distillation help Federated Learning?

Tags: deep-learning, federated-learning

As per my understanding, typically in FL, there is a global server that interacts with various client devices. The global server and the client both possess a ML models. The client(s) update their models locally and then send the weights across to the server where it is averaged.

The [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.11479.pdf), Communication-Efficient On-Device Machine Learning: Federated Distillation and Augmentation under Non-IID Private Data, has the following paragraph - "To rectify this, each device in FD stores per-label mean logit vectors, and periodically uploads these local-average logit vectors to a server. For each label, the uploaded local-average logit vectors from all devices are averaged, resulting in a global-average logit vector per label."

I am really lost with what one can do with "mean logit vectors" of a label. According to me, that's like saying, a dataset consists of 2 labels with the first label coming up 40% of the time and the second 60%. How does this help with prediction? Perhaps my understanding is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

The logit vectors in the aforementioned paper are actually the outputs of the models and not the reference values in the dataset:

> Each model output is a set of logit values normalized via a softmax
> function, hereafter denoted as a logit vector

The average here serves as a proxy for communication efficient comparison of "teacher" and "student" outputs.